# deformation of stable curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a DVR, and $k$ residue field of $R$. We suppose that $X_{0}$ is a stable curve over  Spec$k$.

Dose there exist a stable model $X$ over $R$ such that the special fiber isomorphic to $X_{0}$ ?

If we assume $R=C[[t]]$, where C is complex number field, how to find a deformation which make the generic fiber is smooth?

Comment: If by a stable model you mean a flat family of stable curves, then the answer is "yes" as stable curves have unobstructed deformations (and all formal deformations are algebraic). Probably you can also make the generic fibre smooth by choosing the deformations carefully...

Comment: @anon: Unfortunately the OP did not specify that his DVR is complete (or even just Henselian).  Otherwise your comment is perfectly correct.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the potential non-completeness, thanks! Is the claim clear in the henselian case without excellence assumption?

Comment: @anon: I think the claim is okay in the Henselian case even without excellence (but I need to think it through).  

Comment: @kiseki: Choose a *pluri-canonical* projective embedding $j:X_0\hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}^n_k$, and consider the Hilbert scheme $H$ of $\mathbf{P}^n$ over $R$. By the proof of smoothness of the moduli stack of stable curves (of arithmetic genus $\ge 2$), $H$ is smooth near the point $x_0 \in H(k)$ corresponding to $(X_0,j)$ and stability holds for the universal curve over an open neighborhood of $x_0$. An open $U$ in $H$ around $x_0$ is etale over an affine space, so by approximating an $\widehat{R}$-point of that with an $R$-point we win when R is henselian.

Comment: @ayanta: If we assume that $R$ is a complete DVR, is this deformation unique ?

Comment: @kiseki: No -- just move the coefficients slightly to chase the isomorphism class of the generic fiber without losing stability of the integral model nor affecting the stable reduction (a toy analogue is elliptic curves with multiplicative reduction, for which it would wiggle the non-integral $j$-invariant without changing the reduction).

Comment: @pranavk: If we assume $R=C[[t]]$, where $C$ is complex number field, how to find a deformation which make the generic fiber is smooth?

Comment: Smoothness will hold for a generic deformation, since the nodal locus is étale locally a union of coordinate hyperplanes.  How you write down a particular explicit deformation depends on how $X_0$ is presented to you.

Comment: @kiseki: It sounds like you are looking for some very concrete way to produce a formal deformation that is smooth.  If you choose a "sufficiently ample" invertible sheaf `$\mathcal{L}$` on $X_0$, and if you choose two general global sections `$s_0,s_1\in H^0(X_0,\mathcal{L})$`, then these generate $\mathcal{L}$, hence define a morphism $s:X_0 \to \mathbb{P}^1$.  For $\mathcal{L}$ sufficiently ample and $s_0,s_1$ sufficiently generic, $s$ will be "transverse" in the following sense. contd.


Comment: contd. The sheaf of relative differentials $\Omega_s$ will be the pushforward of an invertible sheaf from a Cartier divisor $D$ in $X_0$ such that no two points of $D$ are contained in a common fiber of $s$, the length of $D$ at every ordinary double point of $X_0$ equals $2$, and the length at every non-double point in the support equals $1$.  The pushforward divisor $s_*D$ is a divisor in $\mathbb{P}^1$ that has length $2$ at the image of every ordinary double point, and has length $1$ at every other point in the support.  contd.

Comment: contd. For every formal deformation of the divisor $s_*D$ in $\mathbb{P}^1$, there exists a corresponding formal deformation of the curve $X_0$ and the morphism $s$.  In particular, for every formal deformation of $s_*D$ to a <I>reduced</I> divisor in $\mathbb{P}^1$, the (generic fiber of the) corresponding deformation of $X_0$ is smooth.

Comment: contd. By the way, a very nice reference for branch divisors of morphisms such as $s$ is the article "Stable Maps and Branch Divisors" by B. Fantechi and R. Pandharipande.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments above fully answer the OP's question.  I am simply collecting some of these into an answer.

First, the answer to the original question is "no" if one does not impose some additional hypothesis on $R$ such as being complete or Henselian.  As with many similar such questions, one negative answer comes from the Harris-Mumford(-Eisenbud) theorem that  $\overline{M}_g$ is non-uniruled for $g\geq 23$.  If $X_0$ is a stable, genus $g$ curve that is reducible with a single node $p$, say $(X',p') \cup (X'',p'')$ where $p$ is identified with the point $p'$ in the first irreducible component $X'$ and with $p''$ in the second irreducible component $X''$, and if $(X',p')$ and $(X'',p'')$ are sufficiently general pointed curves, then there is no deformation to a smooth curve over the (non-complete, non-Henselian) DVR $R=\mathbb{C}[t]_{\langle t \rangle}$.  If there were, this would give a rational curve in $\overline{M}_g$ that intersects a general point of a boundary divisor.  This would imply that a general point of the "interior" is also contained in a rational curve, contradicting the Harris-Mumford(-Eisenbud) theorem.

On the other hand, if $R$ is complete, or just Henselian, then there does exist a deformation.  It is clear from the comments that the OP is looking for a very explicit formulation of this result.  Here is one such formulation.  Every proper curve is projective, and for stable curves, there is even an explicit tensor power of the dualizing sheaf that is very ample.  Thus, assume that $X_0$ is given as a closed curve in some projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Up to re-embedding by a $2$-uple Veronese embedding (only necessary in positive characteristic), a sufficiently general pencil of hyperplane sections is "Lefschetz".  More precisely, for a sufficiently general codimension $2$ linear subspace $L \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ that is disjoint from $X_0$, for the associated linear projection $$\pi_L:(\mathbb{P}^n\setminus L) \to \mathbb{P}^1,$$
the restriction of $\pi_L$ to $X_0$, 
$$\pi:X_0\to \mathbb{P}^1,$$ has sheaf of relative differentials $\Omega_\pi$ that is the pushforward to $X_0$ of an invertible sheaf from an effective Cartier divisor $D$ of $X_0$ with (a) no two distinct points of $D$ are contained in a common fiber of $\pi$, (b) the length of $D$ at every double point of $X_0$ equals $2$, and (c) for every smooth point of $X_0$ contained in $D$, the length of $D$ equals $1$.

The *branch divisor* of $\pi$ is, by definition, $\pi_*D$: an effective Cartier divisor in $\mathbb{P}^1$ that has length $2$ at the image of every double point of $X_0$ and has length $1$ at the image of every other point of $D$.  By the analysis in *Stable Maps and Branch Divisors* of B. Fantechi and R. Pandharipande (the map $\pi$ is a "stable map"), for every formal deformation of the divisor $\pi_* D$ in $\mathbb{P}^1$, there exists a unique formal deformation of the stable map $(X_0,\pi:X_0\to \mathbb{P}^1)$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ such that the associated branch divisor of the deformation equals the deformation of the branch divisor.  In particular, choosing a deformation of $\pi_*D$ to a *reduced* divisor in $\mathbb{P}^1$ gives a formal deformation of $X_0$ to a smooth, stable curve.