# Smoothability of stable curves in mixed characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory, characteristic-p

Let $R$ be a complete DVR with residue field $k$ algebraically closed of characteristic $p$ and fraction field $K$ of characteristic zero. Let $C$ be a stable curve (in the sense of Mumford-Deligne) on $k$. My question is, does there exists a projective surface $X$, flat over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ with special fiber $C$ and generic fiber smooth?

I know that the question has a positive answer in equal characteristic. However, I have not been able to find a similar result in the mixed characteristic case.

Any idea/reference on this question will be most helpful.

Comment: It seems that http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119736/deformation-of-stable-curve contains more or less the same question.

Comment: @Maciekrt Not really. That was exactly my point. The answer here is in equal characteristic, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I guess that what you are asking of your curve over $k$ is the following: Do you even lift?  The answer is, yes, of course I lift! By formal deformation theory and Grothendieck's formal existence theorem, every stable curve lifts over every complete DVR (or even Henselian DVR under some excellence hypotheses) to a family with smooth general fiber.

Comment: To flesh out Jason Starr's comment, the deformation theory of stable curves in Deligne-Mumford provides an explicit description of the universal deformation ring $D$ in such a manner (see pp. 81--82 of that paper) that you can specialize the algebraized universal formal deformation $X$ over $D$ into $R$ with $D\rightarrow R[1/p]$ avoiding the "locus of non-smoothness" for $X$ over $D$ by sending $t_j\in D$ to whatever *non-zero* element $c_j$ you wish in the *square* of the maximal ideal $m_R$ of $R$ and sending $u_i, v_i \in D$ to elements of $m_R$ whose product is $c_i$.

Comment: @JasonStarr and nfdc23 Thank you very much for the answer.